# Normal Subgroups of index 2

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H$ and $K$ be distinct subgroups of $G$  with $[G:H]=2=[G:K]$. 
 
$(i)$ Show that there exist a third subgroup $L$ of $G$ such that  $[G:L]=2$ 
 
 $(ii)$ Express $L$ in terms $G$,$H$ and $K$. 
 
 I tried to use second isomorphism theorem on (i) but i always get an index $4$. Any help and hints would be appreciated!!!

Comment: This looks like a typo to me. $H$ has index $2$, so $L=H$ answers the problem as written.

Comment: OP probably means $L$ distinct from $K$ and $H$.

Comment: Is $G$ a finite group?

Comment: It can be infinite i guess since i cant find a counterexample, or maybe im wrong.

Comment: How about $L=(H \cap K) \cup (H \setminus K)(K \setminus H)$?

Comment: Sorry, i didnt get the part $H \setminus K)(K \setminus H)$ is this a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: $L$ is a subgroup of index $2$ in $G$ consisting of two cosets of the subgroup $(H \cap K)$ (which has index $4$).

Answer (score 3):

Note that since $H\triangleleft G$ and $K\triangleleft G$, then $HK=KH=G$. Thus, $[K\colon K\cap H] = [KH\colon H] = [G\colon H] = 2$, and similarly, $[H\colon K\cap H]=2$. As $K$ and $H$ are normal, $(K\cap H)\triangleleft G$, and $[G:K\cap H] = 4$.

Thus, $G/(K\cap H)$ is a group of order $4$. There are only two groups of order $4$. Only one of them as two distinct subgroups of order $2$.

Comment: Sorry, i already get the flow of the argument.  But what should be $L$?

Comment: @RalphJohn: Well, you should be able to figure it out on the basis of what $G/(K\cap H)$ is.